# Model binder wont pass checkbox value into integer property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate, modelbinder

My user model has an **int** property called active (its an int because I didn't create the model nor the database, its getting used as a boolean..). I'm creating the action `/Users/Edit/` that will be editting the model, so I've got a form with a checkbox for the active property. When the submit button is pressed the model binder will put all the form data together into one single object and pass it as a parameter to `/Users/Edit`.

But when I try to save the changes to the database, I check `ModelState.isValid` and it returns false because the model binder won't change the boolean into an integer.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: A checkbox represents true or false.  Why don't you just use a bool and call it a day?

Comment: because I didnt create the database and in the database its an int

Comment: Are you able to edit the Db? It should be a bit

Comment: Are you using the exact same object type for your view and database?  Ideally you could change your view model and then if you need to fix up the data before going into the database then you can do that when the database model is populated.

Comment: @James I'll have to wait till monday before I can

Comment: If you do that, then make the property a bool. Use DisplayFor in your razor view and it will auto create a checkbox and check it accordingly

Comment: @James I had no idea I could just make the property into a bool while its a tinyint in the database. Thanks dude.

Comment: No Problem. Have fun :) - i will stick it in a solution so you can close this once you implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Edit Db to make it a bit

2) Change the property on your view model to a bool

3) Use DisplayFor in your Razor View

It will now automatically generate a checkbox and check it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume worst case that you cannot change your Db to a bool.  Then you would use a View Model to perform the data transformation for you.

Say your user model is such:

```
public class StaticModel {

    public string description { get; set; }
    public int IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

Then you create a view model (facade style):

```
public class StaticModelFacade {

    StaticModel _value;    

    public StaticModelFacade(StaticModel value) {

        _value = value;

    }

    public string description {
        get {return _value.description;}
        set {_value.description = value;}
    }

    public bool IsActive {
        get { return _value.IsActive = 1; }
        set { _value.IsActive = value ? 1 : 0 }
    }

}
```

Your view now binds to a bool and all is wired up Ok.

Comment: Thanks. James method works for me better since I can just change it to a bool but this is nice to know =)